# javascript select id in different forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new to JS and i am trying to update option value using prompt. I have same ID element in different forms.

I have two forms and both having same IDs:dc_list_Z_side and dc_list_A_side.
Is there a way i can select ID in form using JS?

JS CODE:

```
function add_dc_form_down2() {
    var theSelectA = form_down2.dc_list_A_side;
    if (theSelectA[theSelectA.selectedIndex].value == "zzzzADD DC zzzzzz") {
        var dc_name = prompt("Enter DC Name");
        if (dc_name != null){
            dc_a = document.getElementById("dc_list_A_side")
            dc_a.options[dc_a.selectedIndex].text = dc_name;
            dc_a.options[dc_a.selectedIndex].value = dc_name;
            }
     }
    var theSelectZ = form_down2.dc_list_Z_side;
     if (theSelectZ[theSelectZ.selectedIndex].value == "zzzzADD DC zzzzzz") {
        var dc_name2 = prompt("Enter DC Name");
        if (dc_name2 != null){
             dc_z = document.getElementById("dc_list_Z_side");
             dc_z.options[dc_z.selectedIndex].text = dc_name2;
             dc_z.options[dc_z.selectedIndex].value = dc_name2;
            }
     }
     return false;
}

function add_dc_form_flap() {
    var theSelectA = flap_form.dc_list_A_side;
    if (theSelectA[theSelectA.selectedIndex].value == "zzzzADD DC zzzzzz") {
        var dc_name = prompt("Enter DC Name");
        if (dc_name != null){
            dc_a = document.getElementById("dc_list_A_side")
            dc_a.options[dc_a.selectedIndex].text = dc_name;
            dc_a.options[dc_a.selectedIndex].value = dc_name;
            }
     }
    var theSelectZ = flap_form.dc_list_Z_side;
     if (theSelectZ[theSelectZ.selectedIndex].value == "zzzzADD DC zzzzzz") {
        var dc_name2 = prompt("Enter DC Name");
        if (dc_name2 != null){
             dc_z = document.getElementById("dc_list_Z_side");
             dc_z.options[dc_z.selectedIndex].text = dc_name2;
             dc_z.options[dc_z.selectedIndex].value = dc_name2;
            }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to access different *pages*?  How?  Or do you mean that you're re-using the same `id` on the same page?  Which would be invalid HTML.

Comment: same id in different forms on single HTML Page. Actually, only one form is visible at a time.

Comment: You can't re-use `id` values in the same HTML document.  Otherwise things like `getElementById()` would have no way to know *which* element you mean.  As long as the HTML is invalid, the behavior of the JavaScript is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way i can select ID in form using JS?

No.

If you are speaking about having the same form elements on the same page, using the same id (e.g. "dc_list_A_side") you cannot fetch them with document.getElementById(). The id-attribute has to have a unique value for the whole HTML page. JavaScript does not necessarily rely on valid HTML, but in this case it is simply impossible for JavaScript to achieve what you want.

Consider changing the IDs to "dc_list_A_side_a" and "dc_list_A_side_b" for example.